# My float left divs float off the page if it gets too narrow

Tags: html, css

I didn't find this question so pardon if it is too simple.  I have a bunch of DIV's all the same size.  I got them to float horizontally across the 
page with this:

```
#xx {
    max-height: 180px; overflow-y: hidden;
}
.hflo {
    width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

Then I assigned all the Divs class="hflo"  xx is the id of the parent div.  I didn't assign it a width.  I want the DIVs to march across the page then drop down and start a new row when they hit the right edge not just disappear.

so it is

```
<div id="xx">
   <div class="hflo"> ... </div>
   .
   .
   .
</div>
```

Comment: change `float: left` to `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Then why setting a `max-height` on the parent div ? If you remove it, they start a new row and don't disappear :

```
#xx {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41u15odu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The divs do start a new row, but are hidden because you set the maximum height of `#xx` to 150px. Just remove the `max-height` property or use another `overflow`:

**Solution 1:**

```css
#xx {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```css
#xx {
    max-height: 180px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```